Extract very large zip file on AWS S3 using Lamda Functions
I'm trying to read a very large zip file on a s3 bucket and extract its data on another s3 bucket using the code below as lambda function:
import json
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
import zipfile

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    source_bucket = 'bucket1'
    target_bucket = 'bucket2'
    
    
    
    for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
        if (str(file.key).endswith('.zip')):
            zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=source_bucket, key=file.key)
            buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())
            
            z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
            for filename in z.namelist():
                file_info = z.getinfo(filename)
                try:
                    response = s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
                        z.open(filename),
                        Bucket=target_bucket,
                        Key=f'{filename}'
                        )
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
        else:
            print(file.key + ' is not a zip file.')

Now, the problem is this code reads the whole file into memory and I'm getting MemoryError.
I want to know if there is any more efficient way to dot this? like read the file in chunks?
Thanks.

Have you already configured the maximum RAM for your Lambda function and it's still insufficient?

Yes, I have done that.

Is this a one time thing or do you have to do this regularly?  If it's one time, spin up a good sized EC2 and do it on that.

I want to do this regulary.

Might be relevant: How to zip and unzip files that do not fit in memory with Python

Based on John Rotenstein's comment, I found a way myself using httpx and stream-unzip:
import boto3
from stream_unzip import stream_unzip
import httpx
from io import BytesIO

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

bucket_name = 'bucket_name'

def zipped_chunks():
    with httpx.stream('GET', 'https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/file.zip') as r:
        yield from r.iter_bytes(chunk_size=65536)

for file_name, file_size, unzipped_chunks in stream_unzip(zipped_chunks()):
    s3_key = f'unzipped/{file_name}'.replace("'","")
    
    buffer = BytesIO()
    
    for chunk in unzipped_chunks:
        buffer.write(chunk)
    
    buffer.seek(0)
    
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(buffer, bucket_name, s3_key)
    
    buffer.close()
    
    print(f"File '{file_name}' has been uploaded to S3 bucket '{bucket_name}' with key '{s3_key}'")

